# How to install a Fleck Websocket server on a third party web host

Tags: asp.net, websocket

I am new to websockets and server hosts, but after some study of the source code I understand how Fleck works.

I have a web-hosting account with FastHosts that serves ASP .Net web pages.

Is it possible to somehow run a Fleck HTML5 web socket server up on a host like this? How would I go about installing it? The Fleck source code comes with a simple console application that acts as the server - would it be feasible to run a similar console app on a web server?

Comment: Just to clarify the question: is it feasible and 'correct' to host a server from a simple console application, if the host allows me to get one running? Is this solid and secure enough for say multiplayer gaming? How do other people get around this apart from hosting on a machine sat in their house!?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible your web hosting provider will allow you to run a fleck service (if the machine is capable of running c# applications) but it will depend alot on what your server will do, how heavy on the cpu cycles etc is.  I'd hazzard that most companies will side with "no" (but in my /personal/ experience my hosting company has been very understanding with me in the past.)

EDIT: is it feasable?  Again, it really depends on exactally how intense the service is going to be.  Chat relay for a small website with a handful of users? Sure.  Dedicated MMORPG server? No.

However what most people would do when not running their own boxes at home is rent either a dedicated server or a VPS (virtual private server).  These usually cost a bit more than standard web hosting packages (VPS is cheaper than dedicated however) but allow you full access to install your own servers and other applications, reboot your machine at need, etc.  As its your own server there it's very unlikely you can harm other users of the service - whereas if they let you run your fleck server on the webhosting box and it goes a bit pear shaped.. heh, yeah.

In short, ask your host what they think but expect them to say no and start browsing for a cheap VPS or dedicated server.